When cancelling the "Move messages" popup in chat the select feature doesn't go away
When you open the "move messages" popup, then open the "create new bookmark" popup (or in reverse, doesn't matter), then cancel both of them starting from "create new bookmark" popup (if you cancel the "move messages" popup first it works correctly) you will still be able to select messages, as if though you were still moving messages, though you will not be able to move them without opening the popup again.
The input box works correctly, all other features too, besides being unable to copy the messages and the starwall ones, for some reason.
